# Heat transfer to an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

In thermodynamics, why is the heat that is transferred to an ideal gas considered as work that was done on the system for an isothermal process?

Comment: While you already got a good answer here, in general you should frame your questions to show what you have done to try to the solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I started to study thermodynamics, and we learned about ideal gas in class and while reviewing the material this question raised in my head and I couldn't find an understandable answer on the internet so I asked here. I will be more specific next time:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Chemistry Stack Exchange!

In general, heat transferred to an ideal gas is *not* considered as work that was done on the system. I suspect you're referring to a process in which the internal energy doesn't change: $\Delta{U}=0$. As $\Delta{U} = q + w$ (where q is heat and w is work), in the case where $\Delta{U}=0$ you get $q=-w$. This holds for a general system (not just ideal gases).
For an ideal gas, U only depends on temperature. So for an isothermal process, the internal energy of the ideal gas will not change, and you'll once again get the result $q=-w$.

Comment: Ok. I understand know. Thank you very much for the help:)